# Get specific data from page and write it to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building an online store with javascript shopping cart. However, the script doesn't allow printing only one or two values when displaying cart, but I need to do this.

Here's what the cart looks like:

```
<div class="simpleCart_items">
    <div>
        <div class="headerRow">
            <div class="item-name">Tuote</div>
            <div class="item-price">Hinta</div>
            <div class="item-decrement">-</div>
            <div class="item-quantity">Määrä</div>
            <div class="item-increment">+</div>
            <div class="item-total">Yhteensä</div>
            <div class="item-remove">Poista</div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-1">
            <div class="item-name">Teipit</div>
            <div class="item-price">€0.00</div>
            <div class="item-decrement"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement"><img src="css/minus.png" alt="minus"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-quantity">3</div>
            <div class="item-increment"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment"><img src="css/plus.png" alt="plus"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-total">€0.00</div>
            <div class="item-remove"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove"><img src="css/remove.png" alt="Remove"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemRow row-1 even" id="cartItem_SCI-3">
            <div class="item-name">Car Speaker -hajuste</div>
            <div class="item-price">€4.00</div>
            <div class="item-decrement"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement"><img src="css/minus.png" alt="minus"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-quantity">1</div>
            <div class="item-increment"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment"><img src="css/plus.png" alt="plus"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-total">€4.00</div>
            <div class="item-remove"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove"><img src="css/remove.png" alt="Remove"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="itemRow row-2 odd" id="cartItem_SCI-5">
            <div class="item-name">Teipit (Musta hiilikuitu)</div>
            <div class="item-price">€0.00</div>
            <div class="item-decrement"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_decrement"><img src="css/minus.png" alt="minus"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-quantity">1</div>
            <div class="item-increment"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_increment"><img src="css/plus.png" alt="plus"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item-total">€0.00</div>
            <div class="item-remove"><a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove"><img src="css/remove.png" alt="Remove"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** The cart is written via javascript so it isn't visible in page source, only in inspect mode of the browser.

So how would I gather the `item-name`, `item-price`and `item-quantity`?

I've tried this:

```
    var name = $('.item-name');
    var price = $('.item-price');
    var quantity = $('.item-quantity');
    var data = name + price + quantity;
    $('#items').html(data);
```

But this won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this -> `$('.item-name');`

You are just capturing the element as object but not the value.

Now that you got your element as object, you need to extract the value and, in this case, your element object is a `div` so you can try `.text()` or `.html()` (to get the text or html inside the div).

*(For this situation I will use `text()` cause you are working just with values and there is nothing related to html)*

**Try this:**

```
var name = $('.item-name');
var price = $('.item-price');
var quantity = $('.item-quantity');
var data = name.text() + price.text() + quantity.text();
$('#items').html(data);
```

---

### Better solution:

This will make clickable the `div` in which you have the product and match the **cartItem_SCI** pattern.

So, when user clicks any of the elements of your cart, you will get the `name`, `price` and `quantity` values that will be attached to the `$('#items')` div using `append()` method instead of `html()` *(because using this will replace the product information each time the user clicks a div)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('div[id^="cartItem_SCI-"]').css({ cursor:'pointer' });

    $('div[id^="cartItem_SCI-"]').click(function() {
        var name = $(this).find('.item-name');
        var price = $(this).find('.item-price');
        var quantity = $(this).find('.item-quantity');
        var data = name.text() + ' - ' + price.text() + ' - ' + quantity.text();
        $('#items').append(data + '<br/>');
    });

});​
```

Comment: Okay, but it's not appending anything to #items div.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen I made a correction, take a look at the new code, it is working now :-)

Comment: I only see the .ready event added, and it was inside document ready. What could be possibly going wrong?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Just take a better look. I made a correction, now there is no '$(this).children().find()' it was replaced to '$(this).find(selector)', also added '<br/>' to make a breakline

Comment: But the #items is still empty.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Try this: $('div[id^="cartItem_SCI-"]').on('click', function()... (instead of the line from my post)

Comment: The cart can be displayed with `class="simpleCart_items"` and it isn't displayed anywhere... Could that be it?

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your code, I tested the one I put here and works fine

Comment: I just readed the local storage with another script and used it, it's something with the shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

For one item you can get like this.But since you have multiple items make one object like this .

```
var item={};

$('.item-name').each(function(){item.name=$(this).html()});
$('.item-price').each(function(){item.price=$(this).html()});
$('.item-quantity').each(function(){item.quantity=$(this).html()});


  var data='';    
        for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++)
               {
              data+=item[i].name+item[i].price+item[i].quantity;
                  }
        $('#items').html(data);
```

Comment: Yeah, but it won't print anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are just getting  a reference to the class, add .html() to get the inner html of the element that the class applied to.

```
var name = $('.item-name').html();
```